# unwelcome if statement on luajit

Tags: lua, luajit

*lua 5.3.5* accepts the code below,

```
 function isOdd (n)                                                                                                    
     if n & 1 == 1                                                                                                     
         then return true                                                                                              
         else return false                                                                                             
     end                                                                                                               
 end    

 print(isOdd(1), isOdd(2))
```

Why does *luajit 2.0.5* refuse it?

```
line 2:  'then' expected near '&'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because native bitwise operators are new to Lua 5.3, and LuaJIT is basically Lua 5.1. Use [`bit.band`](https://bitop.luajit.org/api.html) instead:

> This module is a LuaJIT built-in — you don't need to download or install Lua BitOp. The Lua BitOp site has full documentation for all [Lua BitOp API functions](https://bitop.luajit.org/api.html).
>
> Please make sure to `require` the module before using any of its functions:
>
> ```
> local bit = require("bit")
> ```

[Source](https://luajit.org/extensions.html)